# zRSSFeed - Selecting RSS feeds from a menu with ticker animation + jQuery Mobile (PhoneGap)?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, rss

**Problem:** after selecting a feed from the list and pressing a button to return to the home div jQuery reloads the whole page and only the title (without any feeds) of the new selected webpage is shown.
By default, before choosing this specific option (selecting a feed) on another div page, the title ("Reuters Oddly Enough News") and the feeds are being shown without any problems.

**`<div data-role="page">`code below`</div>`**

```
<h4>Select a feed from the list below</h4>
<select id="menu">
                <option value="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">Reuters Oddly Enough News</option>
                <option value="http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list">BBC iPlayer TV Listing</option>
                <option value="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss">CNN News</option>
</select>
```

**Selecting RSS feeds from a menu with ticker animation:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

                setRSSFeed('#menu');  

                $('#menu').change(function() {
                                setRSSFeed(this)
                });

                function setRSSFeed(obj) {
                                var feedurl = $('option:selected', obj).val();

                                if (feedurl) {
                                                $('#test').rssfeed(feedurl,{}, function(e) {
                                                                $(e).find('div.rssBody').vTicker();
                                                });
                                }
                }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the, it works with no problem. Unless I didn't get what you really need.

**zRSSFeed w/ Ticker Animation + Jquery Mobile**

```
$('#menu').on('change', function () {
var selected = $(this).val();
  $('#test').rssfeed(selected,{}, function(e)  {
   $(e).find('div.rssBody').vTicker();
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="content">
     <h4>Select a feed from the list below</h4>

    <select id="menu">
        <option value="#">Choose</option>
        <option value="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">Reuters Oddly Enough News</option>
        <option value="http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list">BBC iPlayer TV Listing</option>
        <option value="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss">CNN News</option>
    </select>
  </div>
 <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```